# How to send form variables to multiple URLs in php (cURL?)

Tags: php, curl

I seem to have run into a problem with trying to submit form variables to multiple urls.
The code i have below takes variables from a form and stores them in php, then I am trying to send those variables to certain urls (the variables do pass through, I've tested that). I heard cUrl is the way to do it, but I don't know if its working cause im stumped on how to to retrieve the response code.

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['firstname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$src = $_POST['srcUrl'];
$ip= $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
$suDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


$data = array(
"fn" => $name,
"src" => $src,
"em" => $email,
"ip" => $ip,
"signupDate" => $suDate
);


$data2 = array(
"firstname" => $name,
"email" => $email,
);

function post_to_url($url, $data) {
$fields = '';
foreach($data as $key => $value) { 
  $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
}
rtrim($fields, '&');

$post = curl_init();

curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($post);

curl_close($post);
}



post_to_url("http://exampleURL.com/page.php", $data);
post_to_url("http://exampleURL2.com/cgi-bin/add.cgi", $data2);



print_r($result);


?>
```

any help is greatly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code example you've provided above, $result contains the response you're looking for. To view the full details of the variable, use this:

```
print_r($result);
```

`print_r` is useful when you're not sure what data type a variable is or what data it might contain. `print_r` gives you all available information on the variable.

**Edit:** Also change `curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));` to `curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`  CURLOPT_POST is a true/false option (http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Comment: Hi, i have included the 'print_r($result);' to get response, but still nothing is showing. I have updated the code to reflect the changes, including submission to to a 2nd url. WIll it still work? thanks, for the help

Comment: @David Maldonado If it's still blank, then you're not getting a response. Try setting CURLOPT_POST to 1, instead of the count().

Comment: this worked really well, thanks for the help. I have one other random question how can i add a little bit more to this script by executing one of those 'post_to_url' functions randomly. ie, hits the script and executes function at random? thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Inside your function where you have `$result = curl_exec($post);` the `$result` data is the response. So you need to add `return $return;` and call the function with `$response = post_to_url(...);` and echo the response.